# Integral with logarithmic and exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a problem with integration of $$\int \frac{1}{2e^tt^2}+\frac{\ln t}{2e^t}\,\mathrm{d}t$$ It seems that the integral has simple solution in terms of elementary functions, but I have no idea which method can be applied there. Any hints and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For the first term let $u=e^{-t}$ and $dv=t^{-2}$. After integration by part twice you will find the integral part cancel the second term.

> $\int e^{-t}t^{-2}+(\ln t)e^{-t}\,dt \\= -e^{-t}t^{-1} - \int e^{-t}t^{-1} + (\ln t)e^{-t}\,dt \\= -e^{-t}t^{-1} - e^{-t}\ln t +\int -e^{-t}\ln t + (\ln t)e^{-t}dt \\= -e^{-t}t^{-1} - e^{-t}\ln t $

Comment: I tried to substitute  $u=e^{-t}$, instead of integrating by parts, thank you

Answer (score 1):

$$-\frac{e^{-t} (t \log (t)+1)}{2 t}$$ differentiate this with respect to $t$